# When using Authorization code grant with the Proof Key of Code Exchange, can't the final access token response be captured by the malicious app?

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, pkce

From what I understood about using Authorization code grant with the Proof Key of Code Exchange in native applications, the auth server sends a response with the access token to the application after validating the original code verifier and comparing it with the code challenge sent initially.

But can't the response with access token be captured by a malicious app and used to access restricted data?

Same question for Single Page Web Apps. If they implement PKCE, can't a browser extension capture the final response with access token?

Comment: This flow (authZ code) was developed to avoid sending access-token in a URL, from where it can be stolen easily in transfer. PKCE one was introduced for non-confidential clients initially, to prove the code does belong to the party invoking /token endpoint. Not sure their purpose is to fight with malicious extensions, which in theory can stole it from your local/session storage.

Answer (score 2):

The specific vulnerability is not related to apps being able to intercept any HTTP requests. It has to do with the redirect from the authorization endpoint back to the app.

After a user is sent to the `redirect_uri` location, a hand-off needs to happen back to the app that originally requested it from a browser.

This hand-off is not terribly secure, other apps can potentially intercept this.

You are right though that if an app is able to intercept any HTTP request/response then PKCE won't help you much.

Answer (score 1):

PKCE only proves that the party conpleting login is the party that started the login. It should be used by all clients according to [OAuth 2.1](https://www.ietf.org/archive/id/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-1-08.html#name-compatibility-with-oauth-20), but does not solve all problems. The best practices vary depending on the application type:

**MOBILE**

You can use [Claimed HTTPS Scheme Based Redirect URIs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-1-1_0.html#native-apps) which restricts token delivery to a redirect URI that only a particular app can access.

**DESKTOP**

The best you can do here is private URI scheme based redirect URIs, perhaps combined with an organization policy to only accept apps from whitelisted sources, eg with trusted code signing that chains up to an approved root CA.

**SPAs**

A [Backend for Frontend](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps#section-6.2) is considered the option with best understood threats, by only returning the latest secure cookies to the browser. An extension might then be able to perform session hijacking, but could not exfiltrate a backend credential for more concerted attacks.